# Лишний отступ в шапке сайта

Tags: html, css

Правлю вот такой сайт http://nostrum.com.ua
Что бы не плодить много текста я скинул ссылку сайта.
Должно быть `header {width: 100%;}` но не работает как нужно...
[image: Баг]

Comment: У меня все выглядит иначе. Часть меню справа, часть внизу от лого. Зеленой подложки нет вообще. Такое впечатление, что скрины с неопубликованной страницы. На стиле `.header p.logo a` очень мешает `float: left;`.

Comment: Спасибо, я решил переверстать а не править эту муть. Пока оставил как есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.header ul.menu`
убрать `width: 1100px;`, добавить `text-align: center;`

`.header ul.menu li`
убрать `float: left;`, добавить `display: inline-block;`
чтобы все элементы влезали в строку меню поиграйте с `padding: 0 28px;`. По-моему 18 или даже 12px лушче смотрится

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо! Я что то подобное пробовал, но не получалось.

Answer (score 1):

для .header нужно указать min-width и max-width:1980px например но что то мне подсказывает что эту всю беду требуется переверстать)

Comment: Буду переверстывать)

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.5);
}
a.logo {
  display: block;
}
a.logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.menu ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <img src="http://nostrum.com.ua/wp-content/themes/naturefox/images/logo.svg">
  </a>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">item 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо, получается что li спрыгивают на новую строку, мне такое не подходит. Человек выше мне подсказал, и все заработало.

Comment: что бы это не происходило добавьте min-height: 1024px; у header

Answer (score 0):

убрать float и переделать все на flexbox. и text-align: center//justify-content:center